# Is it possible to bind to JQuery attr to js variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to bind JQuery attr to js variable like this?

```
var pathToImg = "assets/images/picture1.png"
$("#background-image").attr("href", pathToImg)
```

I want that when I change `pathToImg` depending on state then element `#background-image` changes dynamically.

Does it work like this under hood? While I don't use it. I want to figure out how I can do this?

Comment: No this is not how JS (or any language I know of) works. Changing a variable will not magically update a property. You need to explicitly set that property.

Comment: You need to write your on function that updates the `href` onChange

Comment: Are you sure you need jQuery for that? You can use `document.getElementById('background-image').href = pathToImg;` (though you cannot bind the variable)

Comment: Thanks everybody. Just I want to write less code for this. And I think may be it works under hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, No it doesn't work like that. You need to capture an event when the value of the variable changes and set the value of the attribute again.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not work like that. Use some front-end frameworks like Angular or React that has *state* (obvious not full/valid code, sample in Angular):

```
...
var this.$scope.pathToImg = "assets/images/picture1.png";
...

this.$scope.pathToImg = "assets/images/picture2.png";

<div><img src="{{pathToImg}}"/></div>
```

In jQuery you can use some functions to change it *dynamically*:

```js
var currentIndex = 1;
var baseUrl = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=';

function plus() {
  currentIndex++;
  update();
}

function minus() {
  currentIndex--;
  update();
}

function update() {
  currentIndex = Math.max(1, currentIndex);
  $('#myImg').attr('src', baseUrl+currentIndex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=1" id="myImg"/>
<hr/>
<button onClick="minus()">-</button>
<button onClick="plus()">+</button>
```

Comment: I'm using Angular. But me need to changing application icon dynamically dependings on context of application. As I know in Angular I can use binding only into <ss-root></ss-root>(AppComponent that specify in bootstrap) component in index.html. And for this purpose I try use other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement watcher on js variable and in watcher method write change behaviour code :-

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'pathToImg', { //watcher on js variable
    get: function () { return this._pathToImg; },
    set: function (v) {
        this._pathToImg = v;
        $("#background-image").attr("src", v); //change behaviour code
    }
});
```